# Troubleshooting Craftsman 1/2HP garage opener with 5 blinking lights

Tags: garage-door-opener

After opening the garage door just once yesterday it wouldn't close.

What I've tried w/o success:

1. Clearing obstructions.
2. Realigning sensors. I know its not sensors because when I purposely misalign them I see a different error code.
3. Releasing the garage door opener.
4. Clearing out contacts with an electrical cleaner spray and reseating them. Same with the logic board and RPM sensor.
5. Powered off the unit for 10 hours.
6. Tried the wall unit as well as the remote.

Observations:

1. The unit hums for about 2 seconds and I see 5 blinking lights. Here is a 15 sec clip https://i.stack.imgur.com/LztDZ.jpg
2. The gears are intact and I don't see any shavings indicating wear.
3. The gears do not move at all..
4. The manual indicates 5 lights could be a faulty RPM sensor, overheating motor or faulty logic board.

What else can I do to fix this or eliminate possible issues?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: *After **opening** the garage door just once yesterday it wouldn't **close**.* If you close it manually, does it open? If you close it manually half-way, does it open or close (electrically) at all?

Comment: Hey @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact
When I close it manually it does not open electrically and the motor does not activate. No change in the error code either. How would I close it manually half-way because wouldn't I only be able to do this after disengaging the trolley? Correct me if I'm wrong, but disengaging the trolley would make the motor redundant, right?  Or are you saying to re-engage the trolley and then try to manually close it? Please let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: The specifics will vary on the design. I am no expert on garage door openers (since I don't have a garage...) My understanding (could be wrong) is that electric garage door openers can be operated manually (e.g., in case of power failure) and my idea was to test it from various starting points. But you've already covered the main two - if opened, can't close, if closed, can't open.

Comment: You need to disconnect the trolley and operate the door manually.  You should do this at least monthly so you monitor the health of the garage door.   Doors should move smoothly without much effort.  Effort indicates something is starting to break down with the door mechanism.  Forcing a damaged door will only exacerbate the damage to the point of catastrophic failure, and doors can kill people.  That's why openers shouldn't force doors.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine This is a new property and also the first time I've ever had to operate a door manually. As soon as I disengage the trolley it slides down. The door doesn't slide down the rollers like butter but with a couple of gentle tugs along the way it closes w/o effort. Moving forward I'll keep this is mind.

Comment: Well, you should be able to place the door at any height and it should basically stay there with zero force or at most ounces of force.  If in any position it wants to go to another position, then you have a broken door and the opener is blameless.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine, I saw your post before the edit and I can respect the analogy and call to action. After reading your post I dropped everything to go and check. Disengaged at OPEN position, the door stays there. As I guide it it toward CLOSE, it stays at the newly travelled distance. Its only when its more than half at CLOSE does it begin to display an inclination to move to CLOSE itself. It slowly stops 3/4th of the way where I have to apply some pressure to bring it to full CLOSE. At no point does it want to travel in the opposite direction nor do I have to apply 'strength'.

Comment: @eszed well, that slight imbalance could be the door being heavier than expected e.g. use of uninsulated vs insulated panels or if something was attached to it.  If you can make the door go where you want with a couple of fingers, then we can safely say it's "in tune enough" for a) to not be dangerous, and b) the lifter to handle it.

Comment: Did you by chance install an LED light in the opener? They cause havoc on some openers.

Comment: The previous home owner had an LED bulb which I removed upon taking possession. Its possible they used it extensively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The manual indicates 5 lights could be a faulty RPM sensor, overheating motor or faulty logic board.

To me, that says, in short - it's stuck. Either:

1. The logic board is telling it to do the wrong thing (e.g. continue to open even though you're telling it to close, or something like that.)
2. The RPM sensor is malfunctioning, telling the logic board that it is not moving, so - continue to move, even though it's still trying.
3. The motor is overheating for 1 of two reasons:
   a) The motor is stuck (either mechanically, or because the logic board or RPM sensor are faulty). Hopefully it just got mechanically stuck for some reason.
   b) The motor is bad.

If you disengage the trolly and attempt to close the door, the motor should either spin freely, or the motor will continue to hum. If it continues to hum, then there's nothing mechanical keeping the motor from spinning freely, so it's either a bad motor or bad logic board or sensor(s). At that point, I'd test the motor.

If it spins freely, the motor is probably alright, and it's probably a sensor or logic board. At that point, I'd check the direction the motor is spinning, and move on from there.

Comment: Hey @jgrant When I disengage the trolley the motor continues to hum. In fact there is no change to the symptoms no matter what I do. Is there a way to manually operate the motor to make sure nothing is blocking it? How can I rule out the motor?

Comment: I would uninstall the garage door opener, remove or disconnect the motor from the logic board, and power it directly using the prescribed volts/amps written on the nameplate, which would bypass logic board and potential problems with the coupler.

Comment: Also, with everything off, if your ohm reader reads 1 or nearly 1 when you test the motor contacts, that would be an easy way to confirm that the motor is, in fact, grounded, and therefore bad. And you could do that by just taking it apart enough to access the the motor contacts.

Comment: your 1st comment is out of my capabilities but your 2nd is doable after some learning. I have a multimeter. Meanwhile I removed another board from the opener and noticed a portion of the relay (?) had darkend. Does this indicate damage? https://imgur.com/a/vqnH9kX

Comment: Also, I noticed that this part (orange arrow) was jammed against the nut and that this section of the chain (red arrow) was extremely taut. I loosened this nut (green arrow) and that freed this part (orange). This also allowed me to rotate this gear (purple) with my hands allowing the chain to travel a bit. Could this be a cause? Here are the pics https://imgur.com/a/hMVpEfT

Comment: UPDATE AFTER 8 MONTHS: 
This issue resurfaced thrice since. Each time I noticed the trolley was jammed against the nut in this photo https://imgur.com/a/hMVpEfT
After loosening the tension in the chain the trolley would release and life resumed. This was the original observation when the issue first occured. I hope this update benefits readers.

Answer (score 1):

> The manual indicates 5 lights could be a faulty RPM sensor, overheating motor or faulty logic board.

Therefore, I would suggest testing or replacing the:

- RPM sensor
- Motor
- Logic board

I would work in order of increasing expense since you're shooting in the dark since the manual isn't more specific.

You could probably test the motor by *carefully* putting your hand on it (don't wear anything loose fitting, be sure to avoid any/all moving parts, other general warnings about working on a ladder around moving parts) and see if it strikes you as being excessively hot in the few seconds it runs. It probably won't over heat that quickly, but may have overheated during yesterday's operation and now not be working.

---

I note that, based on the nice pic of the manufacturer plate (thanks for the nice clear picture!), your opener was built in 2008 - it's 14 years old now. You might consider that it may be more cost effective to buy a new one rather than replacing parts. I'd suggest looking at prices for replacement parts vs the cost of a new opener before heading down the road of replacing parts.

Comment: I'd only be letting the budding DIYer in me down by buying a new opener. I see your rationale though but I want to exhaust all reasonable options. I read somewhere that it could be a 'cold solder joint' on the logic board and resoldering it fixed the 5 lights blinking issue for a dozen posters. Never used a soldering kit before but one is on its way and I'd like to at least try that before buying a new opener. I don't think any operating event could've caused the motor to over heat but I will test it.

Answer (score 1):

This afternoon I resoldered some joints on the logic board as a last resort and reassmbled everything. To my surprise the opener started working again.

However, I think what did it was loosening the tension in the chain that freed the trolley because my solder job was pathetic.

In the old pic here https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BQwa.jpg you can see the trolley is likely jammed against the nut (orange arrow).

After loosening it last month I was able to manually rotate the gears creating distance b/w the trolley's final stop and the nut before tightening it again. Now there are 5 inches b/w the two. This probably means the motor was mechanically stuck. Everything sounds and looks OK.

The opener is nearly 15 years old so I purchased a new one last week. I'll hold on to it for now. I took the opportunity to blow dust away and lubricate all moving parts with purpose built lubricant.

I can't pick a specific answer but jgrants' pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the hardware testing, this could be a simple issue of adjusting two screws. Somewhere on the unit are two adjustable screws with slots. Turning them slightly affects the speed and how much the door(s) open/close. Find the manual for your unit and adjust the screws accordingly. Based on the pictures above, I'm betting on the two white nylon screws as being the adjusters. I have had to tweak mine from time to time.

Barring these adjustments, you'll have to troubleshoot the hardware, as others have suggested.

Comment: OK, I'll give it a shot soon. Over enthusiastically I disconnected the wires and took out the logic board to see if there were any weakened solder joints. Nothing visible to this untrained naked eye for now. Once I put it back together I'll adjust the screws.